# Codeigniter duplicate session issue

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, hosting, session-variables

I have an application built with codeigniter using the sessions class and storing session data in a database. The problem is I'm getting extra session records in my database when my webpage loads a css file.

Up until recently I was running my application on a simple VPS host provided by rackspace. Database and Apache were both running on the same VPS. Recently however I've migrated my application to [PHPFog](http://www.phpfog.com) to allow it to scale more easily. I didn't have this issue with 
my former hosting setup.

[image]

The row with the populated value for user_data is my original session. The other three blank sessions are the result of simply refreshing the page three times. I seem to have tracked it down to including a css file in my header, when I comment it out or delete it the issue goes away. It's only this particular css file also, other css/js/image files don't cause this issue.

Here is a link to the css file in question:
http://pastebin.com/XfEBNFiC

Anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I realized the html of the page in question might be helpful. Commenting out the stylesheet include on line 13 makes the issue go away.
http://pastebin.com/iBEb4he6

**UPDATE2:**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cookie Related Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'cookie_prefix' = Set a prefix if you need to avoid collisions
| 'cookie_domain' = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
| 'cookie_path'   =  Typically will be a forward slash
| 'cookie_secure' =  Cookies will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
|
*/

$config['cookie_domain']    = 'casey.phpfogapp.com'; //$base_url_parts['host'];
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Comment: a record being created in my sessions table for every page request? The table would grow rapidly and be full of useless session records that don't actually correlate to a users session. Oh I should probably state that the actual users session doesn't appear to be lost. Session properties/variables are maintained from request to request. It's just these new records appearing out of nowhere.

Comment: I updated the question to contain a link to my html that includes the style sheet

Comment: I have seen problems of duplicated sessions with CI (eventually causing a logout due to a blank session, so this is an issue) all linked to AJAX calls. The css file is always in the head section ? is it hosted on the same server ?

Comment: From the CI User Guide -> " **Note**: The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears out expired sessions so you do not need to write your own routine to do it."

Comment: Whats's your [`session.cookie_domain`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) set to?

Comment: @jondavidjohn, they're not expired sessions they're randomly generated sessions for every page request that don't correspond to a new user. If I refresh the page 50 times I'll have 50 session records in my database.

Comment: @Wrikken, I updated the question to contain my session config values from config.php

Comment: How come only a `vc_ci_session` cookie is set then, with an expiration of `0` => browser closes?

Comment: @Casey Flynn - But they WILL expire, and when they do they will be cleared out, you might point out in your question that the only real problem here is you're worried about space in your database.

Comment: oh apologies, I had briefly turned on a prefix of 'vc_'. If you look at the site again the change should have been made

Comment: @jondavidjohn, sure but the idea of having potentially 50x as many sessions in my database as necessary seems like a big problem in terms of wasted space and lost performance. Plus I'm trying to understand what exactly is causing this since a css file is just a static resource and I'm not sure what in it is causing a new session to appear

Comment: Hmm, I have no extra cookies just loading the css files. Do you perhaps have an auto_prepend/auto_append setting? What happens if you disable the useragent check?

Comment: @Wrikken, I'm unsure about the auto_prepend/auto_append setting? Is that something specific in a codeigniter configuration file? I just turned off the useragent check, and interestingly the same thing happens, but only twice? I can press refresh on the same page and new session records are generated but only twice. I should be clear I have caching disabled in my web browser

Comment: Hm, weird. Let's look at this logically: an CI cookie is set, so an CI file (your config file for instance) is included. Set it up so that when the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` matches the css file you write a `debug_print_backtrace();` to a file. Examine that file and you may know more. `auto_append/prepend` are settings in ini-files/vhost config/.htaccess files, you can check them with `ini_get()`.

Comment: In your css file you have images pointing to your application folder, like thus: url(/application/assets/web/images/_global/preload-small.gif). What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my applications I place the following code into .htaccess for preventing a cookie to be sent with css/js/images requests:

```
#.htaccess

# Use Mod_deflate to compress static files
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
<filesmatch ".(js|css|ico|txt|htm|html|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

# Speed up caching
FileETag MTime Size

# Expires
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 366 days"

# Future Expires Headers
<filesmatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Sat, 27 Dec 2014 23:59:59 GMT"
</filesmatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and the problem was that the CI cookie name cannot have dots in it.

bad cookie name:  .domain.com

smooth criminal:  mydomaincom

I was using the domain name with dots for the cookie name to enable domain wide cookies (share cookies from the main domain to all its subdomains), turns out I've found that the only thing I needed for that was:

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".domain.com";
```